# Адаптация страницы (проблема с картинкой)

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая картинка, после всех манипуляций по изменению размера, фокус её сместился ровно на центр, можно ли этот фокус как-то подвинуть вверх? К примеру top 0 при уменьшении размера, есть ли что-нибудь такое? Или как с этим справляетесь вы?

Comment: Добавьте код того, как это реализовано у Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно что-то вроде этого?

```
background-position: top center;
```